# Value of authentication between services

Tags: authentication, web-application, web-service

I am looking to understand the value of having a non-public service require authentication from other services that are part of the same product. Is it for when someone gains access to some *other* host and then attacks the service?

Comment: If you don't authenticate, how do you know the request is coming from other services that are part of the same product?

Comment: I mean in the event that the (second) service is not accessible on the public internet. For example, if you have a firewall that only allows public access to `ServiceA`, but `ServiceA` must make a call to `ServiceB`, does it make sense for `ServiceB` to perform any authentication, or as long as it's a call behind the firewall no authentication is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if there are any threats that are mitigated in part by authentication in internal service calls, the answer is yes.  If you are asking if it is worth it to do something about it that depends on the cost and the risk.

Here's some of the threats:

1. Server compromised
2. DMZ protections compromised
3. Network appliance logs vulnerable
4. Compromised third party component
5. Malicious employee

Pretty short list.

I don't think it is common to set up internal SSL with client certs unless it is a sensitive application, e.g. something handling CC numbers or other high value target.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits are:

1. If the user is already authenticated, then they seamlessly pass through onto the second system without needing to type in their credentials (i.e., username and password) once again
2. The user only has to remember a single set of credentials.
3. The administrator does not need to manage password synchronisation between the two systems.
4. More secure, because authentication is trust-based using [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), instead of sharing credentials between systems.

Comment: I mean in the event that the (second) service is not accessible on the public internet. For example, if you have a firewall that only allows public access to `ServiceA`, but `ServiceA` must make a call to `ServiceB`, does it make sense for `ServiceB` to perform any authentication, or as long as it's a call behind the firewall no authentication is required?

Answer (score 0):

Usually private services whose customers are other services require *authorization*, not *authentication*. The difference is that the former describes what rights or privileges the request comes with, while the latter defines what entity originated the request.

A database is an example of a private service. Consider an application talking to the database. It matters less that the application authenticate itself to the database, than that the database ensure that the application not have the rights of a DBA, to, for instance, shut down the database or drop all the tables.

Authentication information is often expensive to perform, and once performed with produce authorization information. So authentication is usually uniquely performed once at the "edge" of the system, while the authorization that comes with the single act of authentication should be carried through all the processing that occurs inside the system on behalf of the authenticated entity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I'm interested in sussing out the value: if its authr without _proof_ of identity, authn, it's a bit like why you don't want to use your computer as root - prevent mistakes. For example, your database user doesn't need to be able to drop tables, so if you missed some SQL injection flaw the results are less catastrophic. That said, is there also value in authentication? For this, besides preventing someone who _already_ has access to one of your _other_ services from attacking the service in question, I'm not sure what else it adds.

Comment: It doesn't even help there, someone who is already inside the trust boundary will not be thwarted in practice by internal authentication. Where one sees service-to-service authentication- the value- is in meeting compliance or commercial support requirements. A vendor with a complex product perhaps with compliance duties may want the pieces to use certs to talk to each other on an unfamiliar and potentially poorly managed customer network.

Comment: So do you think it's effectively useless?

Comment: Right now, very generally speaking, service-service authentication, where services are already within a trust boundary, is not a useful expense.